# What is the best way to separate uv?

Tags: uv

I have object unwrapped to one uv, i want to preserve all island sizes and their shapes, but pack them separately. I am using UV Shotpacker. I've separated my model to two materials to use them in Substance Painter, but i want each material to be packed individually. Is there a way to separate them for quite a while, pack and get back together? Maybe there is an easier way?